# Returning a reference and only a reference

Tags: c++

I have the following function which is part of a Grid class:

```
T& select(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    return nodes[x + width * y].element;
}
```

Is there any way I can force the compiler to reject construction of a `T` from returned `T&` without deleting the copy constructor of T (which might not even be a class)?

```
auto n = grid.select(1,1); // this should be illegal
```

Comment: Why not return a pointer?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it can be done without returning a pointer.

Comment: @seanmcl doesn't stop it, just makes it less convenient: `auto n = *grid.select(1,1)`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is returning a wrapper object that has the reference tucked inside with an overloaded `operator ->` to access the members, and/or overloaded `operator *` to access the value. The wrapper would be inexpensive to construct, and you would preserve your reference (as near as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

While you return a reference, what users of the code do with it later is entirely out of your control.  The fact that they can use your reference to create a copy is valid in the language.